# How to successfully submit .Net form using CasperJS

Tags: javascript, asp.net, forms, phantomjs, casperjs

I am trying to submit a .Net form, and then capture elements from the response page.  The .Net form appears to not submit correctly, as CasperJS simply reloads the form page.  The CasperJS example of storing Google search results work fine for me, but this form simply does not load the response page.

```
var casper = require("casper").create({
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: "debug",
});

casper.start("https://jobs.ca.gov/Public/JobVacancySearch.aspx", function(){
    this.fill('#form1', {'ctl00$cphMainContent$txtJobTitle': 'Programmer'}, true);

    this.waitForSelector("#cphMainContent_gvSearchResults");
});

casper.run(function(){
    console.log("success");
});
```

This is the output:

```
casperjs so-test.js --config=<(echo '{"sslProtocol": "any"}') --ignore-ssl-errors=true
[info] [phantom] Starting...
[info] [phantom] Running suite: 2 steps
[debug] [phantom] opening url: https://jobs.ca.gov/Public/JobVacancySearch.aspx, HTTP GET
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://jobs.ca.gov/Public/JobVacancySearch.aspx, type=Other, lock=true, isMainFrame=true
[debug] [phantom] url changed to "https://jobs.ca.gov/Public/JobVacancySearch.aspx"
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://jobs.ca.gov/MasterContent/headerSiteSearch.html, type=Other, lock=true, isMainFrame=false
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://jobs.ca.gov/MasterContent/headerSiteSearch.html, type=Other, lock=true, isMainFrame=false
[debug] [phantom] Successfully injected Casper client-side utilities
[info] [phantom] Step 2/2 https://jobs.ca.gov/Public/JobVacancySearch.aspx (HTTP 200)
[info] [remote] attempting to fetch form element from selector: '#form1'
[debug] [remote] Set "ctl00$cphMainContent$txtJobTitle" field value to Programmer
[info] [remote] submitting form to ./JobVacancySearch.aspx, HTTP POST
[info] [phantom] Step 2/2: done in 2070ms.
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://jobs.ca.gov/Public/JobVacancySearch.aspx, type=FormSubmitted, lock=true, isMainFrame=true
[debug] [phantom] url changed to "https://jobs.ca.gov/Public/JobVacancySearch.aspx"
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://jobs.ca.gov/MasterContent/headerSiteSearch.html, type=Other, lock=true, isMainFrame=false
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://jobs.ca.gov/MasterContent/headerSiteSearch.html, type=Other, lock=true, isMainFrame=false
[debug] [phantom] Successfully injected Casper client-side utilities
[info] [phantom] Step 3/3 https://jobs.ca.gov/Public/JobVacancySearch.aspx (HTTP 200)
[info] [phantom] Step 3/3: done in 2355ms.
[warning] [phantom] Casper.waitFor() timeout
[error] [phantom] Wait timeout of 5000ms expired, exiting.
Wait timeout of 5000ms expired, exiting.
```

Comment: Take a screenshot to see what happened. This would go into the `onTimeout` callback of `waitForSelector`

Comment: The screenshot does not reveal any insight.  No messages on the screen.  The debug messages simply show that when the form is submitted it goes back to the JobVacancySearch.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Clicking the submit button after you fill the form appears to have solved this issue.

```
var casper = require("casper").create({
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: "debug",
});

casper.start("https://jobs.ca.gov/Public/JobVacancySearch.aspx");

casper.then(function(){
    this.fill('#form1', {'ctl00$cphMainContent$txtJobTitle': 'Programmer'}, false);
});

casper.then(function(){
    this.click("#cphMainContent_btnFindJobs"); 
});

casper.waitForSelector("#cphMainContent_gvSearchResults", function(){
    console.log("Found search results");
});

casper.run(function(){
    console.log("success");
    this.exit();
});
```